# PHP - Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php

```
public function get_session() 
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['login'];
        if(isset($id))
        {
            return $id;
        }
    }
```

Resultado

> Notice: Undefined index: login in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PROINSOR\inc\link.class.php on line 47

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: No está definido **login** en el arreglo `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Tienes que mover el `if` y hacer que la comprobación sea directamente sobre `$_SESSION['login']` y no sobre `login` (para entonces el error ya ocurrió)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro como hace? osea

 if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
  {
   return true;
  }

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) return $_SESSION['login'];`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si funciona bien pero es raro. xD

Comment: ¿Por qué es raro?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro porque no funciona ese variable, $id = $_SESSION['login'];
        if(isset($id))
        {
            return $id;
        }

Comment: El problema es que lo que falla es `$_SESSION['login']`, entonces falla la asignación `id=...` antes de llegar a la comprobación del isset

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entendido. gracias

Answer (score 6):

El problema ocurre en la asignación `id = $_SESSION['login'];` porque `$_SESSION['login']` no está definido. No importa que hagas el `isset` porque se está haciendo DESPUÉS de usar `$_SESSION['login']`.

La solución es mover el isset a la condición `if` (y ya de paso puedes simplificar ya que no necesitarás la variable `id`). Algo como esto:

```
public function get_session() 
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        return $_SESSION['login'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hola intenta con lo siguiente:

```
public function get_session() 
    {
        $id = isset($_SESSION['login'])?$_SESSION['login']:0;
        if($id!==0)
        {
            return $id;
        }
    }
```

saludos.

Comment: si esta bien pero por favor me explicas que es "?" y ":0"? para que necesito saber.

Comment: Es una condicional binomial
si existe el primer resultado con el signo de interrogación ? asignas el primer valor, si no con los : dos puntos asignas el otro valor, viene siendo similar a un if, a diferencia del if aqui solo es binomial:

$variable=isset($algo)?$algo:$nada;

es otra forma de hacer validaciones sin usar la sentencia if.

saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás asignas el valor de $_SESSION['id'] a $id sin haber comprobado que la variable de sesión venga con datos, lo puedes solucionar con el siguiente código y sin necesidad de usar la variable $id.

```
public function get_session() 
    {
        if( isset($_SESSION['login']) )
        {
            return $_SESSION['login'];
        }
    }
```